# Universal Music Player says Error Loading Media

Tags: java, android, json, audio-player, android-music-player

I am using `Universal Music Player (UMP)` sample code provided by Google.

Here, I would like to `customize` a thing as per my `requirement`, still `UMP` works in below process:

```
Screen 1: Genres (Songs by genre)

Screen 2: List of Genres

Screen 3: List of Songs (under particular Genre)
```

Now, here is my `requirement`:

I don't need `Screen 1: Genres (Songs by genre)` and I would like to start my app directly from `Screen 2` (i.e : `List of Genres` screen)

To get my target, I have made a small change in `MusicService.java` class.

I have `replaced` below code :

```
/**
     * Actual implementation of onLoadChildren that assumes that MusicProvider is already
     * initialized.
     */
    private void loadChildrenImpl(final String parentMediaId,
                                  final Result<List<MediaBrowser.MediaItem>> result) {
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren: parentMediaId=", parentMediaId);

        List<MediaBrowser.MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();

        if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(parentMediaId)) {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.ROOT");
            mediaItems.add(new MediaBrowser.MediaItem(
                    new MediaDescription.Builder()
                        .setMediaId(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.browse_genres))
                        .setIconUri(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
                                "com.example.android.uamp/drawable/ic_by_genre"))
                        .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.browse_genre_subtitle))
                        .build(), MediaBrowser.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE
            ));

        } else if (MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE.equals(parentMediaId)) {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.GENRES");
            for (String genre : mMusicProvider.getGenres()) {
                MediaBrowser.MediaItem item = new MediaBrowser.MediaItem(
                    new MediaDescription.Builder()
                        .setMediaId(createBrowseCategoryMediaID(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE, genre))
                        .setTitle(genre)
                        .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.browse_musics_by_genre_subtitle, genre))
                        .build(), MediaBrowser.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE
                );
                mediaItems.add(item);
            }

        } else if (parentMediaId.startsWith(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE)) {
            String genre = MediaIDHelper.getHierarchy(parentMediaId)[1];
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.SONGS_BY_GENRE  genre=", genre);
            for (MediaMetadata track : mMusicProvider.getMusicsByGenre(genre)) {
                // Since mediaMetadata fields are immutable, we need to create a copy, so we
                // can set a hierarchy-aware mediaID. We will need to know the media hierarchy
                // when we get a onPlayFromMusicID call, so we can create the proper queue based
                // on where the music was selected from (by artist, by genre, random, etc)
                String hierarchyAwareMediaID = MediaIDHelper.createMediaID(
                        track.getDescription().getMediaId(), MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE, genre);
                MediaMetadata trackCopy = new MediaMetadata.Builder(track)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, hierarchyAwareMediaID)
                        .build();
                MediaBrowser.MediaItem bItem = new MediaBrowser.MediaItem(
                        trackCopy.getDescription(), MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE);
                mediaItems.add(bItem);
            }
        } else {
            LogHelper.w(TAG, "Skipping unmatched parentMediaId: ", parentMediaId);
        }
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren sending ", mediaItems.size(),
                " results for ", parentMediaId);
        result.sendResult(mediaItems);
    }
```

with the `following` code:

```
/**
     * Actual implementation of onLoadChildren that assumes that MusicProvider is already
     * initialized.
     */
    private void loadChildrenImpl(final String parentMediaId,
                                  final Result<List<MediaBrowser.MediaItem>> result) {
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren: parentMediaId=", parentMediaId);

        List<MediaBrowser.MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();

        if (MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE.equals(parentMediaId)) {
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.GENRES");
            for (String genre : mMusicProvider.getGenres()) {
                MediaBrowser.MediaItem item = new MediaBrowser.MediaItem(
                    new MediaDescription.Builder()
                        .setMediaId(createBrowseCategoryMediaID(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE, genre))
                        .setTitle(genre)
                        .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.browse_musics_by_genre_subtitle, genre))
                        .build(), MediaBrowser.MediaItem.FLAG_BROWSABLE
                );
                mediaItems.add(item);
            }

        } else if (parentMediaId.startsWith(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE)) {
            String genre = MediaIDHelper.getHierarchy(parentMediaId)[1];
            LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren.SONGS_BY_GENRE  genre=", genre);
            for (MediaMetadata track : mMusicProvider.getMusicsByGenre(genre)) {
                // Since mediaMetadata fields are immutable, we need to create a copy, so we
                // can set a hierarchy-aware mediaID. We will need to know the media hierarchy
                // when we get a onPlayFromMusicID call, so we can create the proper queue based
                // on where the music was selected from (by artist, by genre, random, etc)
                String hierarchyAwareMediaID = MediaIDHelper.createMediaID(
                        track.getDescription().getMediaId(), MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE, genre);
                MediaMetadata trackCopy = new MediaMetadata.Builder(track)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, hierarchyAwareMediaID)
                        .build();
                MediaBrowser.MediaItem bItem = new MediaBrowser.MediaItem(
                        trackCopy.getDescription(), MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE);
                mediaItems.add(bItem);
            }
        } else {
            LogHelper.w(TAG, "Skipping unmatched parentMediaId: ", parentMediaId);
        }
        LogHelper.d(TAG, "OnLoadChildren sending ", mediaItems.size(),
                " results for ", parentMediaId);
        result.sendResult(mediaItems);
    }
```

And when I launched my app instead of `List of Genres` I got a `message` that says : `"Error Loading Media"`

So `what's wrong` here, `Where I have to make change` in my code ? `To get List of Genres` directly

Comment: post your full stacktrace here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that UMP still calls `loadChildrenImpl()` with `parentMediaId == __ROOT__`.

So it can't find proper case in the if-else statement and ends up in

```
LogHelper.w(TAG, "Skipping unmatched parentMediaId: ", parentMediaId);
```

And returns **empty** `mediaItems`(This is causing "Error Loading Media" error)

The fix is in `MusicService` class, in `onGetRoot()` method replace

```
    return new BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ID_ROOT, null);
```

with

```
    return new BrowserRoot(MEDIA_ID_MUSICS_BY_GENRE, null);
```

Comment: thank you :) I did mistake I have not read onGetRoot() method, I ticked your answer as useful and accepted too, will award you bounty after 18 hours... may I know, Why I am not getting Thumb with Genres ?

Comment: @Sophie you're more than welcome. Regarding Thumbs, in `for (String genre : mMusicProvider.getGenres()) { }` you'll have to call `.setIconUri()` for each genre (i.e. to have all images locally), I'm afraid

Comment: @Sophie i'm good with Ms Yvette's idea to wait a bit with the bounty :-)